# $E$ measurable if and only if $E \cap (a,b)$ is measurable for any interval $(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We take the definition of measurability to be the following: $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is measurable if for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an open set $G$ and a closed set $F$ such that $F \subseteq E \subseteq G$ such that $m^*(G \setminus F) < \varepsilon$, where $m^*$ is Lebesgue outer measure.

On page 279 of Carothers' *Real Analysis*, it is proven that $E$ is measurable if and only if $E \cap (a,b)$ is measurable for any open interval $(a,b)$. In the proof (forward implication), he states that we can take $G_n$ open and $F_n$ closed such that $F_n \subseteq E \cap (n,n+1) \subseteq G_n$ and $m^*(G_n \setminus F_n) < 2^{-|n|}\varepsilon$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I'm OK with this, but then he says "by enlarging $G_n$ slightly, if necessary, we can also suppose both $n,n+1 \in G_n$, and hence $G = \cup_n G_n$ is an open set containing $E$." How does he "enlarge" the sets "slightly"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$G_n$ is a union of open intervals $(\alpha,\beta)$. Add to $G_n$ two more open intervals, $(n-\delta_n,n+\delta_n)$ and $(n+1-\delta_n,n+1+\delta_n)$. This increases the (outer) measure of $G_n$ and therefore of $G_n\setminus F_n$ by at most $4\delta_n$. Since $m^*(G_n\setminus F_n)<2^{-|n|}\varepsilon$, by picking $\delta_n$ small enough, this addition of $4\delta_n$ to the left hand side still results in a strict inequality.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I don't believe the $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ was a typo. We cut $E$ into pieces $E \cap (n,n+1)$ on the whole real line (i.e. $n \in \mathbb{Z}$), not just when $n \geq 0$.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I've edited accordingly.